# Is there a map showing the routes taken in the various Pirates of the Caribbean movies?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean

I would like be able to visualize the 'world' that these movies take place in, and understand the distances involved in each movie.  Has an official or unofficial map ever been made depicting all the places of import, and the routes of each ship in the series?  Even for places that could not be found through conventional means, there is chronological and contextual evidence that should help pin down a likely location.

Comment: My guess is that it's similar to the location of planets in sci-fi movies (i.e. wherever the writers want it to be).

Comment: Take any old Family Circus cartoon with Billy wandering, overlay it on an ocean map, and it ought to work.

Comment: There quite some real life routes in the movies that are described which might be helpful. (Tortuga!) However, some destinations are in secret locations, so that will be a bit of a problem.

Comment: And indeed many of the "secret" locations are reached by deliberately getting lost and sailing in random directions, so there's no chance of working anything out.

Comment: You may as well just use the real-life Caribbean filming locations (where not in a studio).

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I was thinking the same about the real life locations, which would provide a great base for a map.  Secret locations still often include clues.  For instance, reaching the locker required them to sale through frozen seas so it's likely far North.  And the location of the trident was a real place that just happened to be hard to find.  In any case, I had hoped that the writers may have provided some canon or semi-canon details on location.

Comment: @Thunderforge Which doesn't make it any less fun to see the locations plotted, hence the popularity of Star Trek or Star Wars galactic maps.  :)

Comment: could you use the  Mao Kun Map to find the magical places